# Intellij notification for maven build?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

Intellij provides notification as either a sound or a popup.

as mentioned here in the doc
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/notifications.html
and this issue:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-242428/Implement-notification-for-Build-failure-and-Build-succeed-actions

But it doesn't seem to work for my Maven build (for a spring boot project), I am not sure if it is just me or it is not meant to work for Maven?

Has anyone successfully got it working for maven builds? I find it super useful since my build takes more than 5 minutes and I usually switched to a different task while it is building and I want to be notified when the build is done (especially if it failed)

I used to use a plugin called "console beep" to expect certain keyword in the console log to let me know when a build is done. That plugin is not working for me with the latest Intellji release.

[image]

Comment: How do you run your build in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: I use the Run/Debug Configuration -> Maven

Comment: It's not a build from IntelliJ IDEA point of view, it's a run configuration, so you need to vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-285395/System-notification-about-IDEAs-run-configuration-completion.

Answer (score 1):

You can investigate adding a post-build step to your maven build that calls an exe file to print the output you are looking for to the terminal - detect this output and make the beep.

Remember to make this profile dependent. For example -Pbeep